# Opening spinner by clicking on EditText

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

Sorry to bother you guys, but I've been strangling to get this to work.

**What I want it to do:**

EditText to display hint.

User clicks on EditText, opens spinner and selects their sex. That then get's turned into a string and put inside the EditText(gender)

---

**What it is actually doing:**
"Male" the first element in my spinner is already put inside my EditText before the user even clicks on it.(I never see my hint: "Sex")....and the spinner won't open at all when I try clicking on the EditText(gender)

What's going on?

My code:

```
    private Spinner sexSpinner;
    String[] arrayForSpinner = {"Male", "Female"};


    //Inside OnCreate method:
    sexSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_row, arrayForSpinner);
    sexSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


sexSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            gender.setText(sexSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

        }

gender.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(hasFocus){
                sexSpinner.performClick();
            }
        }
    });
```

Layout:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Gender"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/signup_input_gender"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signup_input_birthday"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"/>

<Spinner
        android:background="@color/Blue"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Comment: use [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) for this

Comment: I did not see the code that spinner dropdown when click on edittext?

Comment: @nhoxbypass That would be `gender.setOnFocusChangeListener` job right?

Comment: instead of using edittext you can use textview where you can use hint in textview to show 'sex' as hint to user.

Comment: @lalit-singh-fauzdar UI. I don't want the user to have to type it in.

Comment: @lalit-singh-fauzdar It sorta worked. My hint is still not showing up. The  AutoCompleteTextView is still being pre-populated with the spinner value before the user clicks it, and the spinner stays open after the user selects their sex.

Comment: @lalit-singh-fauzdar Isn't that what you told me to change it to? Hint shows up now with dhruv-patel's code. But as I stated in my reply to him, the Spinner is staying open after I select the gender, and it won't let me select "Male" first, I have to select "Female" then click on "Male"

Comment: I'm answering the question, wait for 2-3 minutes.

Comment: Answer updated although it took me 14 minutes :p.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, I'm showing how to use an `AutoCompleteTextView` for this. Additionally, as I'm copying all the code from my project, I'm also adding the `Imageview` (delete button) I use to reset the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

**First the XML code** (Working with `ConstraintLayout`)**:**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:hint="Select Gender"
        android:id="@+id/acT1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textAlignment="center"            
        android:dropDownHeight="155dp"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:inputType="none"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/acT1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/acT1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/acT1"
        android:alpha=".2"
        android:id="@+id/delButton"
        android:contentDescription="Delete Button" />
```

**Now the Java Code:**

```
        AutoCompleteTextView acTV1 = findViewById(R.id.acT1);
        ImageView delButton = findViewById(R.id.delButton);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources()
            .getStringArray(R.array.Gender_Names));
        String selection;
        acTV1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        acTV1.setCursorVisible(false);
        acTV1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                acTV1.showDropDown();              
                selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selection,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                delButton.setAlpha(.8f);
            }
        });

        acTV1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View arg0) {
                acTV1.showDropDown();
            }
        });

        delButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                acTV1.setText(null);
                delButton.setAlpha(.2f);
                selection = null;                               
            }
        });
```

**And the Gender_Names Array, define it in strings.xml:**

```
 <string-array name="Gender_Names">
    <item>Male</item>
    <item>Female</item>  
    <item>Other</item>      
</string-array>
```

This is how it looks:

1. Empty

[image: Empty]

2. With some data selected

[image]

The whole thing is a copy-paste unless you're not using `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Thanks allot man, I'm implementing it right now. I'll get back to you in a few minutes and let you know.

Comment: @ngx311 No problem mate.

Comment: The best solution is to replace native Spinner control.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you want by this:

Add this in your xml instead of edittext and spinner

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
   android:id="@+id/gender_list"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
   android:ems="10"
   android:editable="false" >
```

and this in your java code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, GENDERLIST);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.gender_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textView.showDropDown();
            textView.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To show `Spinner` ( use gender.setOnClickListener()),

```
gender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                flag = true;              
                sexSpinner.performClick();
            }
        });
```

To show hint first time as a 'Sex' define boolean globle variable 'flag',

```
    boolean flag = false;        // Here
.
.
.
sexSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (flag)        // Here
                    gender.setText(sexSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }
        });
.
.
.
gender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                flag = true;        // Here
                sexSpinner.performClick();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can Accept my answer if that helps by clicking on tick mark... :)

Answer (score 0):

you had not made the spinner visiable while clicking on it so you cant see it

```
sexSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
sexSpinner.setVisibility(View.Invisible)
        gender.setText(sexSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

    }

gender.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(hasFocus){
sexSpinner.setVisibility(View.Visible)
            sexSpinner.performClick();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But my spinner is still not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

change to use AutoCompleteTextView for signup_input_gender, its showDropDown() will show the list (defined in the resource of R.array.Gender_Names)

```
fun setupGenderWithDropdown() {
        val genderEditText = findViewById(R.id.signup_input_gender)
        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, resources.getStringArray(R.array.Gender_Names)
        )
        genderEditText.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
        genderEditText.setOnClickListener {
            genderEditText.showDropDown()
        }
    }
```